# Shared OpenGL resources: delete with finalize() or implement reference counting?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, reference-counting, finalize

I write a 3d model library.

Many different models, can share same OpenGL resources, as textures, buffers, programs, vertex-attribute-objects etc.

When a model is not needed anymore, I delete it. So, if OpenGL resources go unreferenced, must be deleted too, with OpenGL API commands.

So, what of the following is better to implement?

- Set OpenGL API command for delete OpenGL resources inside `finalize()` of object. I read in many articles that `finalize()` is a devil. I believe it, because GC can be called at any time (after OpenGL context destruction), or not at all.
- Implement reference-counting system for java classes which handle OpenGL resources. This needs lot of code and it is like reinvent the wheel, because GC already works with reference-counting.

So, what is the best approach in cases like that?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, `finalize` is always wrong. The GC won't get called when you have enough *heap memory*... and in the meantime you may run out of the OpenGL resources. This just can't work.

> GC can be called at any time (after OpenGL context destruction)

This isn't the problem (assuming that an unreferenced resource may be freed anytime; there might be threading- and order-related problems), the problem is that it may get called too late for you.

> because GC already works with reference-counting.

It does not. It uses a much more efficient approach which (unlike reference-counting) can handle cycles. The cost is the non-determinism biting you, when you deal with other resources.